# how to load html files within the application in javafx

Tags: webview, javafx

i am using **jdk1.7.0_45** for building javafx project,loads pre created html site from my application,found  passing this url **file:///E:/web/index.html**
but which is not my requirement,need to load from my app,so please tell me anyone,the **folder name** need to place in **javafx** app.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the question is that you want to package a static HTML file with your application and display it in a WebView.

You can do it with code like this (Scala syntax but the meaning should be clear):

```
val url = getClass getResource "index.html"

webView.getEngine load url.toString
```

In this example, the `index.html` file (and any related content) must reside in the same package as the class of the code. E.g. if the class is `mypackage.myapp.MyApp`, the file must be in the `mypackage.myapp` package.

If your build system provides an e.g. `resources` folder, it would be good practice to use that for static content such as this. I.e., for this example, create a package `mypackage.myapp` in the resources folder and place the html file there.